# What to do if string sent to SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery is too long?

Tags: c#

The string that I create to insert into a table is about 2,070 characters long and I think it's why I get this error when I send it to ExecuteNonQuery: *The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. The RPC name is invalid.*.

If I copy/paste the string from the debugger into sql server management studio and run, it'll insert correctly. That's why I assume it's the string length.

My question: is there any way to run this insert statement? There are 77 values, so a stored procedure would need to accept all those parameters and the parameters may not always be in that same order.

I can always send the Insert statement as a string parameter to a generic stored procedure that just executes dynamic sql, but I tend to avoid dynamic sql altogether.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you paste your code here too.

Comment: What is your .NET version?

Comment: Create a view in SQL Server and invoke that instead?

Comment: I cannot paste code. There are 77 proprietary columns, just imagine if I posted that here.

Comment: Sorry about that. I use VS2010 and the project is in framework 4.

Comment: How would a view help? I need to insert all those values into the table.

Comment: I'd look to your table design. Relational databases do better by relating fields among many tables of few columns, rather than few tables of many columns. That many fields to insert is an indication that something else is wrong.

Comment: I understand, but there's no relationship that I can use to "divide" the counters into different tables. If that were the case I wouldn't have posted here. The most I could is divide it arbitrarily into several tables, ie. table_1, Table_2, etc.

Answer (score 9):

It was my error.

The method that executes ExecuteNonQuery also has commandType parameter that I wasn't specifying. So by default it would run the text as CommandType.StoredProcedure.

Comment: My mistake also :-/

Comment: This is correct. The error is basically trying to tell you that the command type you have or have not specified does not match the content you are trying to provide